# Add the test case name to capabilities for Browserstack in webdriver-io config

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io, npx, browserstack

I'm using webdriver-io with javascript and I need to include the test case name in the capabilities so that Browserstack shows the correct name

The line `name: process.env.TEST_NAME` is the one that I actually need to change, I execute the test cases using `wdio ./config/wdio.ios.browserstack.conf.js --spec ./path/to/spec.js`

```
config.capabilities = [{
  project: "My project",
  build: `Build Number`,
  name: process.env.TEST_NAME,
  device: 'iPhone 11 Pro',
  os_version: "15",
  maxInstances: 1,
  app: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_APP_ID,
  deviceOrientation: 'portrait',
  'appium.noReset': true,
  'browserstack.debug': true,
  "appium.newCommandTimeout": 1000, 
  'appium.xcodeOrgId': 'SomeID',
  'appium.xcodeSigningId': 'iPhone Developer',
  'appium.automationName': 'XCUITest',
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I do not have enough reputation to add a comment on your question,
but as far as I am aware, you can put any string value for name parameter.

```
name:"any name"
```

should be fine. is it showing something entirely different on the dashboard?

Answer (score -2):

The capabilities for Browserstack are passed as a static JSON.

Ideally, the file path would not get honored.

Comment: youre asking a question in an answer.

Comment: I required additional details to better understand the problem.

Comment: thats what comments are used for.

Comment: I don't yet have the privilege to add comments everywhere yet.